# How can I make multiple HTTP RequestResponse requests to the same long running AWS Lambda function from Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I understand I can invoke AWS Lambda function synchronously and read results:

```
data = invoke_response['Payload'].read()
```

How do I keep connecting to the same long running Lambda function invocation to get partial results until it finishes?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't using the boto3 lambda client in your example. What you can do however is monitor your CloudWatch logs.

1) Post the partial results you would like to see to the logger inside your lambda function.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
def my_logging_handler(event, context):
    results = "something half done"
    logger.info('MY PARTIAL RESULTS'.format(results))
    logger.error('something went wrong')
    return 'Hello from Lambda!'
```

2) Start your lambda asynchronously

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    InvocationType='Event' # To invoke asynchronously InvocationType must be Event,
    LogType='None'|'Tail',
    ClientContext='string',
    Payload=b'bytes'|file,
    Qualifier='string'
)
```

3) Create a loop that calls [GetLogEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html) over a specified time interval for the log stream associated with your lambda.

```
Request Syntax:
{
   "endTime": number,
   "limit": number,
   "logGroupName": "string",
   "logStreamName": "string",
   "nextToken": "string",
   "startFromHead": boolean,
   "startTime": number
}
```

4) Extract the partial results from the log stream response

```
Response Syntax:
{
   "events": [ 
      { 
         "ingestionTime": number,
         "message": "string", # The partial response you posted will be seen here
         "timestamp": number
      }
   ],
   "nextBackwardToken": "string",
   "nextForwardToken": "string"
}
```